# Is the first distance that gets assigned to a node in BFS always the shortest distance?

Tags: graphs, search-algorithms, directed-graphs, breadth-first-search

Consider the following bfs pseudo code that calculates distances of all nodes from $s$ in graph $G=(V,E)$.

[image]

I know that if $G$ was undirected and unweighted, then the above bfs would calculate correct distances.

However, I'm not sure if it would still work if $G$ is directed and unweighted. Basically, what I'm asking is this:

Is the first (non-infinity) distance that gets assigned to each node in bfs always the smallest distance from $s$ if our graph is directed and unweighted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

You can imagine that instead of pop one node at a time, you can pop all nodes. Then enqueue all unvisited nodes that connected from one of the popped nodes. This imagination does not change the actual algorithm at all.

At the first batch operation, the source node $s$ is popped out. The nodes connected from $s$ are all the nodes of distance 1. They are enqueued.

At the next batch operation, all nodes of distance 1 are popped out and all nodes of distance 2 are enqueued.

At the next batch operation, all nodes of distance 2 are popped out and all nodes of distance 3 are enqueued.

And so on.

The above understanding/reasoning works for undirected graph as well as directed graph.

(Similarly, Dijkstra's algorithm works the same for both weighted undirected graph and weighted directed graph.)